# Finding the closest number in a random set

Tags: algorithm, math, set

Say I got a set of 10 random numbers between 0 and 100.

An operator gives me also a random number between 0 and 100.
Then I got to find the number in the set that is the closest from the number the operator gave me.

### example

set = {1,10,34,39,69,89,94,96,98,100}

operator number = 45

return = 39

And how do translate this into code? (javascript or something)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

if set is ordered, do a binary search to find the value, (or the 2 values) that are closest. Then distinguish which of 2 is closest by ...   subtracting?

If set is not ordered, just iterate through the set, (Sorting it would itself take more than one pass), and for each member, check to see if the difference is smaller than the smallest difference you have seen so far,  and if it is, record it as the new smallest difference, and that number as the new candidate answer. .

```
  public int FindClosest(int targetVal, int[] set)
  {
      int dif = 100, cand = 0;
      foreach(int x in set)
          if (Math.Abs(x-targetVal) < dif)
          {
              dif = Math.Abs(x-targetVal);
              cand = x;
          }
      return cand;
  }
```

Comment: If such search is performed often, it can pay off to sort the array, if it is not.

Comment: If set is unordered, won;t sorting the array take longer than making one pass through unordered list ?

Comment: @Charles Bretana: The key is that SebastianK said "if such search is performed often." Let's say that we have `n` numbers among which we are trying to find the closest and we are going to do this `m` times. If we don't sort, then the time complexity is `O(mn)`. If we do sort, then the complexity is `O(n log n + m log n)` because sorting is `O(n log n)` and binary searching is `O(log n)`. If `m >> n` then the time complexity is `O(m log n)` which is better than `O(mn)`.

Comment: @Jason,  Assuming sorted array is persisted for next search, you are right, SebastianK is correct.

Answer (score 6):

- given an array called `input`, create another array of the same size
- each element of this new array is the `Math.abs(input[i] - operatorNumber)`
- select the index of the mininum element (let's call it `k`)
- your answer is `input[k]`

**NB**

- sorting is not needed
- you can do it without the extra array

### Sample implementation in JavaScript

```
function closestTo(number, set) {
    var closest = set[0];
    var prev = Math.abs(set[0] - number);

    for (var i = 1; i < set.length; i++) {
        var diff = Math.abs(set[i] - number);

        if (diff < prev) {
            prev = diff;
            closest = set[i];
        }
    }

    return closest;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

1) Put the set into a binary tree.
2) Insert the operator number into the tree
3) Return the Operators parent

Answer (score 1):

1. order the set
2. binary search for the input
3. if you end up between two elements, check the difference, and return the one with the smallest difference.

Comment: Sorting the set takes O(n log n). I think there's a O(n) solution

Comment: The sort is O(n log n), once. If you need to check once, then the O(n) of checking every value is better. If you need to check quite often, then the one off O(n log n), and then subsequent O(log n) for each check is much better.

Answer (score 1):

Someone tagged this question Mathematica, so here's a Mathematica answer:

```
set = {1,10,34,39,69,89,94,96,98,100};

opno = 45;

set[[Flatten[
  Position[set - opno, i_ /; Abs[i] == Min[Abs[set - opno]]]]]]
```

It works when there are multiple elements of set equally distant from the operator number.

Comment: Nice solution!  (I removed the mathematica tag in the meantime, presuming that it was not intended.  The original author can put it back if I presumed wrong.)

Answer (score 0):

python example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random
from operator import itemgetter

sample = random.sample(range(100), 10)
pivot = random.randint(0, 100)

print 'sample: ', sample
print 'pivot:', pivot
print 'closest:', sample[
    sorted(
        map(lambda i, e: (i, abs(e - pivot)), range(10), sample), 
        key=itemgetter(1)
    )[1][0]]

# sample:  [61, 2, 3, 85, 15, 18, 19, 8, 66, 4]
# pivot: 51
# closest: 66
```