# find the closest number which is higher or lower than x

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

If I have an array which is 'dynamic', e.g:

```
var xArray = [2,4,5,5,6,7,8,9,9,8,7,7,6,6,6]
```

I need to find the closest number (in terms of INDEX) to the last entry, which is not equal to the last entry (in terms of NUMBER)

Kind of hard to explain! So in the case of the array above, the last entry is 6. I'm looking for the closest entry which is different to 6 (could be higher or lower value). in this case it would be

```
xArray[11] //7
```

so at the moment I have:

```
var lastX = xArray[xArray.length -1],
prevX = ?????
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding the closest number in a random set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881609/finding-the-closest-number-in-a-random-set)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like :

```
function diff(arr) {
    var a = arr.slice(), last = a.pop(), nxt = a.pop();
    while (last == nxt && a.length) nxt = a.pop();
    return nxt;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/XL5He/2/)

call it like

```
var diff = diff(xArray);
```

Comment: Quite smart, just maybe add an information for OP that he might want to copy the array first

Comment: thanks this was the easiest for me! used to detect the last drag direction when xArray is an array of event.originalEvent.touches[0].pageX

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var xArray = [2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 8, 7, 7, 6, 6, 6]
var index = xArray.length - 1,
    num = xArray[index];
while (--index >= 0 && xArray[index] == num);
console.log(index)
//here num will be 11
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZCDLe/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var xArray = [2,4,5,5,6,7,8,9,9,8,7,7,6,6,6];
var xChangeDetector = null;

for(var I=xArray.length-1; I>=0 ; I--)
{
   if(xChangeDetector == null)
     {
        xChangeDetector = xArray[I];
     }
   else if(xChangeDetector != xArray[I])
     {
        xChangeDetector = xArray[I];
        break;
     }       
}

alert(xChangeDetector);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zhK7r/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function firstDifferent(arr) {
    for (var i=arr.length-2; i>=0; i--) {
        if (arr[i] != arr[arr.length - 1])
            return i;
    }
}

var xArray = [2,4,5,5,6,7,8,9,9,8,7,7,6,6,6];
var different = firstDifferent(xArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

A functional solution could be this one:

```
var array = [2,4,5,5,6,7,8,9,9,8,7,7,6,6,6]
var lastIndex = array.reduce(function(acc,item,index,arr){ 
                               return item !== arr[acc] ? index : acc 
                             }, 0) -1;

console.log(lastIndex);
```

It is not as efficient as the others because it needs to iterate through the entire array.